# How to write and read a json file in ionic

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic to make an app and I need store some data and read, I don't know how to do, you can give me some directions? So... be more specific... In this app have an option to see the history of order(is a buy app), so everytime an user make an order I need save and when he wish he can see all order what he makes, to do this I need load all json from storage and show, and i dont know how to save of the right way to read dynamically after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [$cordovaFile](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/file/) services :

```
const fileName = "orders.json"

var getUserOrders = function () {

    var d = $q.defer(),
        userOrders;

        $cordovaFile.checkFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, fileName).then(
        function (success) {
            $cordovaFile.readAsText(cordova.file.dataDirectory, fileName).then(
                function (data) {
                    d.resolve(JSON.parse(data));
                }, function (error) {
                    ...
                });  
        }, function (error) {
            // No orders saved
             d.resolve([]);
        }
    );
};

var saveAnOrder = function (order) {

    var d = $q.defer(),
        orderToSave = order;

    getUserOrders().then(
       function (data) {
           var userOrders = data;
           userOrders.push(orderToSave);
            $cordovaFile.writeFile(cordova.file.dataDirectory, fileName, JSON.stringify(userOrders), true).then(
                function (success) {
                     d.resolve(userOrders);
                }, function (error) {
                    ...
                });
        }, function (error) {
           ...
        }
    );
};
```

Comment: you can explain how I can implement this because I can't understand whats happening, i'm new

Comment: You can implement it in a basic Angular service. My example is not very tricky, so if you don't see how to implement it, I invite you to follow the AngularJS tutorial : https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial

Comment: thank you :), I did some tutorials but services and factory i dont understand what they represent in the code